# Trying to extract private key from pfx using windows API

Tags: pfx

Is there a `Microsoft API` equivalent of the following `OpenSSL` (extracts `private key` from `.pfx` file and saves as a new file) ?

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -nocerts -out mycert.key -passin pass:Password -passout pass:Password
```

Comment: Take a look at [`X509Certificate2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: I've been exploring X509Certificate2. I can get private key data, but I need to get the data in the same format as I would from the OpenSSL command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)YOUR_CERTIFICATE.PrivateKey;
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(streamWriter);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa);
pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Private);
streamWriter.Flush();

string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer()).Trim();
int index_of_footer = output.IndexOf("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
memoryStream.Close();
streamWriter.Close();
string PrivKey = output.Substring(0, index_of_footer + 29);
```